# Weight setting performance

Tags: android, performance

*I heard that the **Weight** setting inside **Layout Parameters** can dramatically incrase app's performance. So I am going to use it cautiously, or better - completely avoid using it...*

What is **the best performance** way to build **Button that fills 2/3 of avalible width** and **second Button using the rest (1/3 of width)**?

*and*

What is **the best performance** way to build **Button that fills 100dp of avalible width** and **second Button using the rest**?

*Yes, I searched it, but didn't find nothing about the performance, really!* :)

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I am going to use it cautiously, or better - completely avoid using it...

Get this thought out of your head quickly. `layout_weight` can be very handy in the right situations. I would definitely not rule out using it completely. As far as cautiously, I'm not sure what your concerns are but if you use it properly then you will be fine.

> What is the best performance way to build Button that fills 2/3 of avalible width and second Button using the rest (1/3 of width)?

The main thing to remember when using `layout_weight` is that your `width` of child `View`s should be 0dp with a horizontal `LinearLayout` and your `height` 0dp when using a vertical `LinearLayout`. See below for a short example. Using `layout_weight` can help keep your `layouts` looking the same on different screen sizes/resolutions. If you do something like the below code and don't declare a `weightSum` in your parent `LinearLayout` then the CPU will calculate it for you. You only need to declare `weightSum` if you are doing something where you want empty space or maybe other cases but in general it is best to let it be calculated for you.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button
    ...
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button
    ...
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

> What is the best performance way to build Button that fills 100dp of avalible width and second Button using the rest?

Using a `LinearLayout` you can set the `width` of your first `Button` to 100dp and the `width` of your second `Button` to `match_parent`. This will result in your first `Button` being drawn first and your second `Button` will use the available `width`.

Answer (score 1):

You can and should use layout_weight when it makes your XML easier. It won't be a problem unless you are having very deep, nested layouts (which is not the case when simply aligning two buttons).

If you worry about performance, take a look at the hierarchy viewer every now and then and check if your layout trees are not too large. Click on one of the top right buttons that estimates the measure/layout/draw times, and see if there are any red dots. Those layouts are possibly too slow, and might need to be optimised.

In general; layout_weights are not that bad.

About implementing, use layout weights for the first question, and 100dp & fill_parent width for the second ( inside linear).